# Missing production secret_key_base in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4

I have recently deployed an app and got an internal server error because of missing production `secret_key_base`. After hours of testing, I managed to solve this problem with two methods:

**Method 1:**

I generated a new secret_key with `rake secret` and replaced it with `<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>` in `secrets.yml`. Deployed the app again and this time it worked. **But I think that this method is wrong.**

**Method 2:**

I generated a new secret_key with `rake secret` and added it to `environments/production.rb` like `config.secret_key_base = 'd1f4810e662acf46a33960e3aa5bd0************************`, without changing `secrets.yml` (default is `production: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`). Deployed the app again and it works fine.

**My questions:**

1. Which method is the best?
2. If the 2nd method is correct, why rails does not generate a secret_key_base in *production.rb* by default?
3. Is there any other method to do that?

Comment: Method 2 is still working in my server. Yet I need to run `bundle exec rake secret` command instead `rake secret` to get appropriate secret key.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**For local development**
Generate a secret using `rails secret`

Method #1: Store this secret in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/356441/how-to-add-permanent-environment-variable-in-zsh for

Method #2: Use the *dotenv Gem*

Once you have this gem installed, you then create a `.env` file in the root of your Rails app that does NOT get checked-into the source control.

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Method #3 (if using `rhc` Openshift client)

```
    rhc set-env SECRET_KEY_BASE=3dc8b0885b3043c0e38aa2e1dc64******************** -a myapp
```

**For the server**
Method #1: Heroku

Option 1: Store the SECRET_KEY_BASE directly onto the environment
`heroku config:set SECRET_KEY_BASE=xxxx`

Option 2: Store the secret encrypted with the app and use the `master.key` file to decrypt it.

Method #2:
For AWS, use AWS Secret Manager to store the master key.

Method #3:  *For RHC Openshift*

connect to your server via SSH and run `env` so you should see your SECRET_KEY_BASE in the list.

Now restart you app `rhc app-stop myapp` and `rhc app-start myapp`

Comment: This rhc method is only useable when you host at  openshift.redhat.com?

Comment: You can find appropriate method for each service in its docs. For example for heroku you can check this page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Eventually I ended up with raking a secret on my VPS and putting it in my secrets.yml file.

Comment: similar support in AWS Elastic Beanstalk -- you deploy your rails app and then either use the elastic beanstalk CLI or the web console to create a key after the app's been deployed

Answer (score 6):

If you're on a normal Ubuntu machine just put `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=" <<< output from rake secret here >>> "` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Run `source ~/.bashrc` and restart the app.

Answer (score 3):

There is another option that should be a little more secure and that is to add it to the Apache/Nginx configuration file. I'm using Apache and have just used:

```
SetEnv SECRET_KEY_BASE my_secret
```

Then just leave the secrets.yml file set to:

```
production: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

For a production web server I'm not sure it's valid to assume that a `.bashrc` file is run and will get your ENV variable set, but I think this way is certain to set it. I'm not and expert so ready to have any risks or reasons why it's not a good idea pointed out to me.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is correct. You don't want to store your secrets in the code.

Comment: Why not? It answers all 3 questions: "My questions:

Which method is the best?
If the 2nd method is correct, why rails does not generate a secret_key_base in production.rb by default?
Is there any other method to do that?" Besides that, it explains why.

Comment: You could if you don't have the code on public repository or if on public repository, it should be ignored with gitignore

Comment: Even with a private repository, it's a security risk to store production secrets in source control. Only the production runtime environment "needs to know" those secrets, but with a VCS there are now extra copies on all hosts that have a checkout/clone of the repo, including dev boxes, CI hosts, etc. This makes it much harder to protect (or even understand) the true exposure surface of production secrets.